# laravel 5.5 custom library creation middleware $request->user returns null

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

Hi I have problem with auth()->user() or $request->user() in new fresh library in /vendor/myCustom/src/Middleware/aMdl.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $right)
{
    return var_dump($request->user()); <------ Here i get NULL

    if($request->user()->hasRights($right)){
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect("/");
}
```

Here is a simple service provider

```
public function boot()
{


    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__."/views", 'aFolder');
}

/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    include __DIR__."/routes.php";
    $this->app->make("aCustomlib\aFolder\Controllers\aController");
}
```

A simple route.

```
 Route::get("/aPath", "aCustomlib\aFolder\Controllers\aController@index");
```

I registered the middleware in Kernel.php

Then im just calling in __constructor in aController.php

```
$this->middleware('rights:aRight');
```

I know that names are silly named but its just an example and Im just learning.

Thanks for an answer.

PS: All these files are in /vendor folder

**This happens even if I use in the __constructor(){ $this->middleware('auth')**

Comment: Where did you register the middleware? before or after `SessionStart`?

Comment: I have regitered it in /app/Http/Kernel.php at end of array $routeMiddleware. 'rights' => \aCustomlib\aFolder\Middleware\aMdl::class. Im tried to create similar middleware like RedirectIfAuthenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your routes within the `web` middleware group (starts and populates the session related data), for example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    include __DIR__."/routes.php";
});
```